# Understanding app hashes on facebook app

Tags: android, facebook

When I try and click the button "Log in with Facebook", the loading animation appears and nothing happens. If I remove all hashes it opens the login screen but fails saying there are no hashes present. Am I supposed to be using developer or release hashes? What exactly am I missing here? I'm generating the hashes with this code:

```
try {
            PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
                    "PACKAGE",
                    PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
            for (android.content.pm.Signature signature : info.signatures) {
                MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
                md.update(signature.toByteArray());
                Log.wtf("KeyHash:", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
            }
        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {

        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {

        }
```

**EDIT:**

I have the following code for the facebook login in an android Fragment:

```
    loginButton = (LoginButton) fragment.findViewById(R.id.login_button);
    loginButton.setReadPermissions("user_friends");
    // If using in a fragment
    loginButton.setFragment(this);
    // Other app specific specialization

    // Callback registration
    loginButton.registerCallback(C.callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {

            Log.wtf("onSuccess",loginResult.toString());

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {

            Log.wtf("onCancel","");
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
            Log.wtf("onError",exception.toString());
        }
    });
```

Comment: In debug mode, you use debug hash. You have to set a hash in your Facebook app, in order to Login. Could you should your login code?

Comment: If your hash is correct and set in Facebook dev side, you have to use breakpoints on your callbacks to understand why is it failing/being cancelled.

Answer (score 0):

You should test it as developer and check facebook app settings as well as permission in manifest to be sure check here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started/

Comment: done that five times... am I supposed to change something before I can begin to test the app? If I click the sign in button, a loading animation appears and then nothing happens what does that mean?